# REST API call to filter resource

Tags: rest

I'm building a REST API, i have a resource say Movies.

```
1) POST : movies/

2). GET : movies/{movie_id}
```

call 1) creates a post.

call 2) when movie_id supplied, it returns specific movie's details, otherwise returns all movies.

Now i have to filter out the movies based on movie attributes like popular, rating etc

My doubts is :

Should there be separate URL for filtering the movies something like

```
GET: movies/filter/
```

This call will have GET parameters like popuplar, rating etc And based on those parameters movies can be filtered out.

Not sure what is the standard way to handle this case, please share your thoughts on this,

Comment: Seems a nice way to go, as this clearly defines what each request is supposed to do.

Comment: Yeah, query parameters should be a good way to go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen two basic approaches in this case. One is the one you suggested, which is to use a separate URL `movies/filter/` and filter them out. The classic example is `cars/colors/red/maker/porsche`.

The other is to use query params, which is, when possible, my preferred approach.

```
GET /movies?year=2010&actor=Carrey
```

Variants can include multiples of each (URL encoded appropriately, of course)

```
GET /movies?year=[2010,2011]&actor=Carrey
```

I like this approach because it clearly says, "get a list of movies, but limit by these properties".

Two variants I have seen and sometimes used, when necessary, are attempts to separate out actual search terms in query params from other submissions. These generally come up when you need to use query params for things other than search.

The first is a hybrid, that says, "only search, and treat query params as search terms, in a particular sub path. So something like:

```
GET /movies/filter?year=2010&actor=Carrey
```

Or if you prefer

```
GET /movies/search?year=2010&actor=Carrey
```

A variant is to flag any search terms

```
GET /movies?search.year=2010&search.actor=Carrey
```

Finally, a variant I do *not* like much is to have a `/search` path

```
GET /search/movies?year=2010&actor=Carrey
```

It sometimes is necessary, but I do not like it because `search` is an *action*, not a *resource*, and thus is not very RESTful of a path. But others may like it.